# no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<node*>::push_back(Node*&)’

Tags: c++

I am trying to `push_back` a node pointer into a `vector`, but I am getting an error, I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left, *right;

    Node(int x){
        int data = x;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

vector < struct node* > par,chi,val;

void travel(struct Node* root, struct Node* parent)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    return ;

    travel(root-> left, root);

    par.push_back(parent);
    chi.push_back(root);
    val.push_back(root->data);

    travel(root-> right, root);
}
```

Comment: What is a `struct node` (*vs*. `struct Node`)?

Comment: You don't need `struct Node` outside of defining `Node`

Answer (score 0):

So far everything seems correct

Once try to change

```
vector < struct node* > par,chi,val;
```

with

```
vector < struct Node* > par,chi,val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but has two mistake.

Replace `node*` with `Node*`while declaring a `Node*` type `vector`.

`vector < struct node* > par,chi,val;`should be replaced with `vector < struct Node* > par,chi,val;`

```
vector < struct Node* > par,chi,val;
```

There is another mistake.

You declared val as a `Node*` type vector. But you are trying to push there an integer value.
I think it should be integer type vector.
Just declare `val` as `int` type vector.

```
vector < struct Node* > par,chi;
vector < int > val;
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: Also, the constructor does not initialize the `data` member variable, it initializes a local variable which goes away when the constructor returns.